# Class XXX missing "Meta.model" attribute

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I Trying get list of objects using DRF, But Getting  Error like "**missing "Meta.model attribute"**

Serialzers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import  Car


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model: Car
        fields=['brand_name','model_name','car_color']
```

Views.py Code Below:

```
from app2.serializers import CarSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class BrandList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

URLS.py:

```
from app2.views import ,BrandList

    path("BrandList/", BrandList.as_view(), name="BrandList"),
```

Please someone get out from this

Answer (score 0):

Try models = instead of : in serializers.py

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields=['brand_name','model_name','car_color']
```